# Symfony4 : The annotation does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded (Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints)

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, symfony4, symfony-validator

I'm working on a Symfony4 application and I have this error :

> [Semantical Error] The annotation
> "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank" in property
> App\Entity\Product::$brochure does not exist, or could not be
> auto-loaded.

Here is the `Product`class:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the product brochure as a PDF file.")
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "application/pdf" })
     */
    private $brochure;
    
    public function getBrochure()
    {
        return $this->brochure;
    }

    public function setBrochure($brochure)
    {
        $this->brochure = $brochure;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    // ... getters & setters for price & description

    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }
}
```

The annotation `@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File` makes also an error.

Maybe, I forgot to configure something in Symfony, I don't know.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Where do you call it ? When do you need it ? Isn't it a probleme of `use namespace\of\Product` missing in your code ?

Comment: runtime error i guess it occur when you put or post some data .. make sure you pass brochure value and it is not blank

Comment: I've got the error when I synchronise my code with my database with the command `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should mention that in the composer file, cause in symfony 4 every dependency will automatically loaded and installed via the flex

```
    "require": {
#...
        "symfony/validator": "^3.3",

    },
```

Comment: For Symfony 4 you can use "symfony/validator": "^4.0" ;)

Comment: Work for me... Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but this didn't work for me because I already used flex to install symfony\validator (which adds it to the composer.json manifest). Any other ideas?-

Answer (score 5):

Well this is one of those "I feel stupid" fixes for me. I had installed the package with flex but was still getting the error. The reason being was I typed the Assert statement example found in the symfony documentation, but on my fairly high DPI monitor the back slash looked like a pipe, i.e.:
@Assert|NotBlank(), but it should have been @Assert\NotBlank()

Comment: duh. You are not alone.

Comment: Wow, now I feel stupid too. It really looked like a pip though