# Can't load classes of Validator component in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, validation

[screen shot of my entity class file form PhpStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTTmi.png)

As seen in the screenshot I am trying to use Symfony Validator Component but for some reason, it doesn't see the component.

Things I did to try to resolve this problem:
-checked if there is Validator component declared in composer.json
-run composer update
-run composer dump-autoload 
-tried implementing some validation like NotBlank() or Lenght() and I didn't even show any errors
-checked if the classes exist, and in fact, all component files are there in `app/vendor/symfony/validator`
-checked if I have finder component ( i do have finder component )
-checked if other components work ( for example twig extension works fine ) it seems this error only occurs in Validator component

I found this [Symfony4 : The annotation does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded (Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741971/symfony4-the-annotation-does-not-exist-or-could-not-be-auto-loaded-symfony-c) to be closest to my problem, however, none of the solutions mentioned there solved my problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it with composer / flex, try to launch into your console this:

```
composer require symfony/validator
```

To be sure launch this to reload libraries:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

After that you could use Validator component with a simple use like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints;
```

Comment: same error @Donm? Have you tried to clear the cache?

Comment: Yes i did cleared cache several times. I even reinstalled this component couple of times, clearing cache along the way and still nothing.